# Open existing screen in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am opening an existing aspx page in a jquery dialog but when the page loads the css of the parent screen is overridden by the dialog box screen. How can I prevent that. I cannot change the existing screen. If there is any other dialog that I can use l?

Comment: Load the dialog content into an iframe - it's the only way to separate the css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load an HTML file that include one or more CSS file, these CSS are gonna be "GLOBAL", as always for CSS. The only way is to write CSS in a way that they do not override each other. Just use classes with different names or different id.

I suggest you to do not load CSS with jquery dialog and write those you need for dialogs in a general file of CSS, so things wont change when you load it.